# Is it possible to group emails in outlook by parts of the subject?

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to somehow group emails in Outlook 2016 not by the complete subject line but only by parts (e.g. the beginning) of it? I'm receiving several hundred jira emails per day and it would be great if I could group them by issue# (e.g. group by using the first 20 characters)

Comment: You could write a `VBA` macro which is executed for every incoming mail via rule script and set the mail `category` field to the issue number. Then, you could group the mails according to their `category` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily newer versions of jira support batching of notifications so that I don't require the grouping in outlook anymore :) - see https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-email-notifications-938847633.html?#Configuringemailnotifications-batching for more details.

Comment: For me that answer solves my question, is it ok to select it as accepted answer?